# Does this function sort integers from smallest to largest?

Tags: c, function, sorting

I just wanna know if the following code works correctly for sorting a linked list of integers from smallest to largest value.

```
void list_sort(list_t * list) {

   int i, j;
   int best_index, best_move, best_value;

   ASSERT(list_is_ok(list));

   for (i = 0; i < list->size-1; i++) {

      best_index = i;
      best_value = list->value[i];

      for (j = i+1; j < list->size; j++) {
         if (list->value[j] > best_value) {
            best_index = j;
            best_value = list->value[j];
         }
      }

      if (best_index != i) {

         best_move = list->move[best_index];
         ASSERT(best_value==list->value[best_index]);

         for (j = best_index; j > i; j--) {
            list->move[j] = list->move[j-1];
            list->value[j] = list->value[j-1];
         }

         list->move[i] = best_move;
         list->value[i] = best_value;
      }
   }
```

I just wanna know if the following code works correctly for sorting a linked list of integers from smallest to largest value.

Comment: why don't you call it and see yourself?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for testing and debugging. "Does my code work" is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Maybe better move to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "I just wanna know if the following code works correctly". Luckily for you there is a well known way to achieve that. It's called "testing".

Comment: @s952163 No, Code Review is not an appropriate place for this question. Code Review very specifically only allows code that is already working. So it is a "how to improve" site, not a "is this working" site.

Comment: I want to believe what you meant to say was "is this a solid algorithm for sorting integers(ie. is there a commonly used method that outperforms this one." If you really meant to say "will you see if this works for me", you'll need to give a really good reason as to why the above criticism is not justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code posted does not sort integers from smallest to largest, it does exactly the opposite, it sorts the array `list->value` from largest to smallest and performs the same permutation on the array `list->move` to keep it in sync.

Note that this sort implementation is stable, but inefficient: time-complexity of **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**

To perform the sort by increasing order, change this:

```
if (list->value[j] > best_value) {
```

into this:

```
if (list->value[j] < best_value) {
```

Also note that instead of shifting the array contents, you could just swap the entries at index `i` and `best_index`.  It would be faster, but would break the stability of the sort.